# How can I get the current time in Java correctly?

Tags: c#, java, time

What is the corresponding Java code for this piece of C# code?

```
public static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long Now
{
    get { return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - Epoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
}
```

I know I could calculate this with a `Date` object, but isn't the `Calendar` from Java different from how C#'s DateTime?

At the moment I use this piece o' Java:

```
public static long getCurrentTimeMillis(){
    TimeZone here = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Time time = new Time(here.toString());
    time.setToNow();
    return time.toMillis(false);
}
```

But the differences between the two pieces of code are significant... The C# code has over 1.5 million milliseconds more then the Java code...
How could I get the correct time in milliseconds from the Java code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

This is unixtime with millisecond resolution, aka milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970, [the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Convert this to your alternative epoch:

```
long Offset = new Date(100, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
long DotNetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - Offset;
```

Of course, calculating this offset once and making it a constant would be advisable.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, but this isn't working for me... This solution returns the same value as what I was getting with the code I gave... The issue arises when I send stuff from Java to C#, then the time isn't correct any more... 
`Traffic arrived at: 353082422807 milleseconds.
Traffic sent at: 1299767222623 milleseconds.
Delay between sending & receiving: -946684799816 milleseconds.` This is what I get when testing the code... The arrived value is calculated in C#, the sent was calculated in Java...

Comment: I guess my estimate of over 1.5 million milliseconds more was a bit low... :p

Comment: Change your C# epoch to 1/1-1970

Comment: Can't do that.. It isn't my code and it's part of something bigger... when I try to change that, it will affect a lot more things than what I want it to change... Hence the question how to change this in Java...

Comment: This solution doesn't work... It only worsens it... I think the whole issue is because C#'s `DateTime` counts from 01/01/0001 @ 00:00:00.0

Comment: Your C# function apparently returns milliseconds since 2000/01/01. The java code I showed you do the same. Am I misunderstanding the C# code?

Comment: Not at all.. it get's the time since 0001/01/01 and subtracts the time since 2000/01/01. But the Java code doesn't do that...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, Date constructor takes a 0-based month. Sample corrected

Comment: It still won't work though... Even trying to create an offset on the year 0 doesn't work, as this value is treated as the year 1900... (Recovered from the Javadoc on Date).

Comment: At this moment I get `Traffic arrived at: 353086055581 milleseconds.
Traffic sent at: 353086055530 milleseconds.
Delay between sending & receiving: 51 milleseconds.` But this is after applying my own sollution... Nevertheless, thank you for your time and effort...

Comment: NVM - Yet another mistake on my part. Updated code now to account for java Date taking year as offset from 1900.

Answer (score 3):

System.currentTimeMillis() is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```